# GTest - how to prepare data for multiple usage via SetUp method?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to run some google tests, and I have quite a lot of code to repeat in each test fixture, so I want to make the code as brief as possible, and I would like to use the SetUp method of the child class of Testing::test parent class, but the TEST_F fixtures do not recognize the variables from SetUp

This is the simplest example I can come up with:

```
class FooTest: public testing::Test
      {
      protected:
        virtual void SetUp() // using void SetUp() override does not help
        {
          int FooVar = 911;
        }

        virtual void TearDown()
        {
        }
      };

TEST_F(FooTest, SampleTest)
{
  // FooTest::SetUp(); // This does not help as well
  EXPECT_EQ(911, FooVar);
}
```

When I try to compile this code it shows an error that FooVar was not declared in this scope. How can I fix it?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: You need to declare `FooVar` as a member of the class. At present, it is a local variable inside the `SetUp` method.

Comment: You are declaring `FooVar` in `int FooVar = 911;`. How is it possible that compiler shows that error?

Comment: @M.A Thank you, I did not realize that. Could you please add an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FooVar` is a local variable inside the `SetUp` method. If you want to use it in the test fixtures, it needs to be a class member:

```
class FooTest: public testing::Test
{
      protected:

      int FooVar;
      virtual void SetUp() override
      {
        this.FooVar = 911;
      }
};
```

In this example, if you are only setting integral types, should just make them const member variables.